# Conditional multiplicaiton of two dataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a first dataFrame which looks like this

```
              value  origin
id
Loss_2000_0  611264    2000
Loss_2000_1  644563    2000
Loss_2000_2  555245    2000
Loss_2000_3  572451    2000
Loss_2001_0  496761    2001
...             ...     ...
Loss_2014_1   68247    2014
Loss_2014_2   33820    2014
Loss_2014_3   63882    2014
Loss_2014_4   39578    2014
Loss_2014_5   51357    2014
```

And I have a second dataFrame

```
           LDF
ult   1.273796
2000  1.045484
2001  1.066983
2002  1.094516
2003  1.068604
2004  1.112227
2005  1.098801
2006  1.093077
2007  1.123588
2008  1.135084
2009  1.182663
2010  1.202442
2011  1.229210
2012  1.355516
2013  1.386031
2014  2.122421
```

I would like to create a third dataFrame similar to the first, but in which the `value` is multiplied by `2.122421` if `origin` is `2014`, by `1.386031` if `origin` is `2013`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is more of a programming question it would be better suited to the stackoverflow stackexchange page, but you would be able to achieve this by joining the two dataframes. This would look something like this:

```
(
    df1
    # join the two dataframes based on the year
    .merge(df2, left_on="origin", right_on="ult")
    # multiply the value column with the value in the LDF column
    .assign(new_value = lambda x: x["value"] * x["LDF"]
)
```